# cli/C++ how to define cli::array with unmanaged type element?

Tags: c++-cli

I have a native C/C++ struct

```
typedef struct
{
...
} AStruct;
```

and in C++/CLI code i define one delegate and one cli array as following

```
public delegate void UpdateDataDelegate(AStruct% aSt,AStruct% bSt);

cli::Array<AStruct>^ args=gcnew cli::Array<AStruct>(2); // complile failed!!!!。

this->Invoke(updateData,args);
```

`AStruct` has many fields and was used by many modules so if i don't like to write a mananged wrap  for `AStruct`, how to make above code works?

many thanks

Comment: What is updateData? Why UpdateDataDelegate accepts two AStruct parameters, and you try to create AStruct array?

Comment: What's wrong with using a native container (e.g. `std::vector`) to store your native data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element type of a managed array must be a managed type.  One workaround is store pointers:

```
array<AStruct*>^ args=gcnew array<AStruct*>(2);
args[0] = new AStruct;
// etc...

UpdateDataDelegate^ dlg = gcnew UpdateDataDelegate(Mumble);
dlg->Invoke(*args[0], *args[1]);
```

Comment: Better: it must be a managed type *or a primitive type*.  That's why pointers are permitted.

Comment: By what definition of "managed type" is a pointer a managed type?  It's not managed by the garbage collector, and it is usable in an unmanaged program.

Comment: Ecma-335.  Other big hints are that you can use them in C#, a language that doesn't support generating unmanaged code, and being able to store them in an array.

Comment: Conversely, that could simply mean that C# supports both managed types and primitive types (in fact it does).

Comment: The phrase "managed type" appears in ECMA-335 exactly twice, and both times the behavior mentioned does not apply to pointers (pointers have fixed layout, according to ECMA-335 managed types do not).