# C++/CLI array of unmanaged type passed as pointer

Tags: c#, c++-cli, unmanagedresources

My question carries forward the issue from
[cli/C++ how to define cli::array with unmanaged type element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694748/cli-c-how-to-define-cliarray-with-unmanaged-type-element)

I understand that to create a managed array with an unmanaged type, I need to supply its pointer so.

```
array<UserType*>^ args=gcnew array<UserType*>(2);
```

Now if I want to send this array to a native function expecting a `const UserType*` parameter, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pin_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh%28VS.80%29.aspx). The managed array may not have a fixed address (it can be relocated by the garbage collector).

EDIT: You have an array of `UserType*` so your unmanaged function should be expecting a `UserType* const*` instead.

Comment: could you possibly add a code snippet? i've already tried using the pin_ptr but i'm probably not doing it right.

Comment: It's more likely that the signature of the native function is already determined, in which case the managed array needs to be changed to `cli::array<UserType>^` (not pointer).

Comment: wouldn't cli::array<UserType>^ be disallowed since I cannot create a managed array using a user-defined unmanaged type? (btw modifying the unmanaged type is not an option)